# Unambiguous and compact way to display dates of different timezones in their respective timezones along with daylight information

Tags: dates, time-zones

General Question:

How best to show dates in their respective timezones together in an unambiguous and compact way? How to show whether dates are adjusted for daylight savings or not?

Scenario:

I have couple of date columns in tabular data shown in a table. Dates in the table are shown in their respective timezones. There is also table summary separate from tabular data. Table summary shows dates in a predefined timezone selected by user. The example follows.

Problems:

1. First problem is that values in timezone column are long. The timezone identifier (EST, EDT, UTC) could be used, but all timezones does not have an identifier. I want to know other possible UX options.
2. Information about daylight adjustment is not shown.

Example:

```
    Start Date  | End Date      |  Timezone     |  Other 10-15 Columns
    12/13/2014  | 12/19/2015    |  Eastern Time |  Some data
    06/13/2014  | 12/19/2015    |  Eastern Time |  Some data
    01/01/2014  | 02/19/2015    |  Pacific Time |  Some data

    SUMMARY
    Net start date: 01/01/2014 (in Mountain Time)
    Net end date: 12/19/2015 (in Mountain Time)
```

This question is different from [that question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/525/unambiguous-way-to-display-timezone-information-in-a-compact-manner) as that question does not talk about daylight savings adjustment. But this question is about showing dates in different timezones along with showing whether dates are adjusted for daylight savings or not.

Comment: Can you clarify what about the answers in the [question you link to](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/525/unambiguous-way-to-display-timezone-information-in-a-compact-manner) doesn't answer your question?  Is there a reason you need to show timezone and adjustment separately instead of just relativizing the time for the user?

Comment: Why do you need to display time zone at all, particularly when you are only showing dates?

Comment: Also, how does displaying daylight savings adjustment for a date span make sense?  One of your date spans is 18 months.  There were 3 different clock adjustments during that period.